# Material UI IconButton outline none is not working

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I try to apply css like below example

```
<CustomColorIconButton>
    <DeleteForeverIcon />
</CustomColorIconButton> 

const CustomColorIconButton = withStyles({
    root: {
        color: "#ff8833",
        outline: 'none',
    }
})(IconButton);
```

this is also i try

```
<IconButton classes={{outline: 'none'}} >
    <DeleteForeverIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: Your problem is not nicely described. Is it that you have this black circle around your ButtonIcon even though you set outline to none?

Comment: This black circle could as well be border. You should show a bit more of your code.

Comment: Hello i am using material ui "IconButton" component above but problem is that when i click the button it show black outline and dont want this black outline..just want to remove that black outline

Comment: @Kamleshsharma Are you sure if the `DeleteForeverIcon` doesn't have the outline originally? Can you post how you imported the icon?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem with your code is from just this snippet. Can you try to replicate the problem in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or a [codepen](https://codepen.io) and post a link to it?

Comment: Thanks everyone I style "IconButton" with 'withStyles' and apply css on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is some other setting for styling this button, like in theme config file, setting the outline to 0 should fix this problem: `outline: 0,`

You should also try to see if there is somewhere else in your project some setting for buttons in general where outline is set to some other value than the one that you want. It could be that that setting is somehow overriding this one that you are using.

Also, you can try with setting the value of this parameter as `!important`